# Spring pass entity to super class

Tags: spring, jpa-2.0, autowired

i've created generic super-class like this:

```
@Repository
public class RootQueryCreator<T> {

   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager em;

   private T entity;
   CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = null;
   CriteriaQuery<T> criteriaQuery = null;
   Root<T> rootTable = null;

   public RootQueryCreator() {}

   public RootQueryCreator(T entity) {
    super();
    this.entity = entity;
   }

   @PostConstruct
   public void initRootQuery() {
    criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    criteriaQuery = (CriteriaQuery<T>) 
    criteriaBuilder.createQuery(this.entity.getClass());        
    rootTable = (Root<T>) criteriaQuery.from(entity.getClass());
}}
```

This superclass will be used by each DAOImpl-Class from the Entity.
Like this:

```
@Repository
@Qualifier("myEntitiyClass")
public class MyEntityDAOImpl  extends 
RootQueryCreator<MyEntity> { 

@Autowired
public MyEntityDAOImpl() {
    super(new MyEntity()); //pass any Entity for the Root-Class from Criteria-Framework
}

@Override
public List<MyEntity> getAll() throws Exception {
    super.getCriteriaQuery().select(super.rootTable);
    return super.getEm().createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
}

public List<MyEntity> retrieveData(){

}}
```

And each DAOImpl-Class will be aotowired into some service-class like this:

```
@Service
public class myLecture {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("myEntitiyClass")
private JpaRepositority<MyEntityDAOImpl> myEntityDAOImpl;

public void retrieveData(){

     myEntityDAOImpl.retrieveData();
} }
```

And in the end i get this error:

> IllegalStateException: Autowired annotation requires at least one
>   argument: MyEntityDAOImpl()

Actually i don't need to pass any Entity to DAOImpl-Class.
What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Autowired` annotation specifies  :

> Marks a constructor, field, setter method or config method as to be
>   autowired by Spring's dependency injection facilities.

But you annotated the constructor with `@Autowired` without providing  any dependency as argument :

```
@Autowired
public MyEntityDAOImpl() { //-> Empty arg is the issue here
    super(new MyEntity()); //pass any Entity for the Root-Class from Criteria-Framework
}
```

Whereas the exception :

> IllegalStateException: Autowired annotation requires at least one
>   argument: MyEntityDAOImpl()

In fact you don't need to autowire anything in `MyEntityDAOImpl` as it doesn't require any dependency in its constructor.  So just remove the annotation and let Spring to invoke the constructor as a plain constructor :

```
public MyEntityDAOImpl() {
    super(new MyEntity()); //pass any Entity for the Root-Class from Criteria-Framework
}
```

Comment: Thx. it seems to work. Additionaly i've removed @Repository-Annotation from the super-class. Because after instantiation  from super-class by children-class with passing some entity to superclass, the IoC-Container starts to instantiate Super-Class again as a bean. But on second time i dont pass anywhere any entity and get nullpointer-exception

Comment: You are welcome. The annotation is indeed not required and may be harmful as you noticed. Note also that the parent class should be abstract if it is not designed to be instantiated.